# Can anyone identify this curve produced by a capacitive sensor?

Tags: curves

#### Background

I have made a tubular capacitive liquid level sensor ([This](https://www.reventec.com/product/ls100/) is a professional one, for example). It outputs a frequency that is inversely proportional to the capacitance.

#### The problem

I have taken readings and put them into an Excel spreadsheet, along with the depth of water when they were taken. They seem to be logarithmic, but they are not. I have taken the natural logarithm and normalized the values, and plotted this versus the percentage of submersion of the sensor.

This is the graph:

[image]

X is percentage submerged, Y is reading. "Log Normalized" is the plot of the normalized logarithm values. "Linear" is the plot of the expected/wanted values. "Diff" is the difference between the "Log Normalized" value and the "Linear" value for each pair of those values.

In the final application, I will have a reading, and will will need to find the depth of the water the sensor is in.
**So I have a point along "Log Normalized", I know its Y-position, and I want to find its X-position (percentage submerged). If I can identify "Diff", I can use that formula to get "Linear" from "Log Normalized".**

This is the spreadsheet:
[spreadsheet of readings](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtvcAGZ7KmQUgYxQcvVgj0wcyE7LdA?e=UDUxuO)

[Cross-posted on electronics.stackexchange.com.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/547228/can-anyone-identify-this-curve-produced-by-a-capacitive-sensor)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far. Also, please use mathjax over spreadsheet uploads.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I could not post the image directly myself because I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: What is the best way to insert the contents of the spreadsheet using MathJax?

Comment: You might want to ask this on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe something like $(1 - x)/(1 + ax)$ with $a > 0$?

Comment: Since you're not trying to extrapolate outside the given range of values, a low-degree polynomial (quadratic or cubic) approximation to the blue curve (or its inverse, since that's how you want to evaluate it) should work well.

Comment: @ Karl As I said in reply to a similar comment on Electronics Stack, I will probably use this approach. @ Rural Reader, I will try out this approach tomorrow, thanks.